# FastApi: Parse a JSon into a model that can have different attributes

Tags: python, fastapi

I am just starting with FastAPI and i have to parse a JSON that comes in the body of a POST request. The problem is that one of the attributes may change depending on the type of object we are using, for example, this POST.

```
@router.post('/')
def method(body: Body):

    list, request = body.list, body.request
```

will be parsed into something like this:

```
class Body(BaseModel):
  list: InfoClass = Field(..., title="list")
  request: Request = Field(..., title="Request")
  ("I would like to add the Request2 here")
```

List is always the same but request may change, for example, it can be one of those:

```
 class Request(BaseModel):
   a: str
   b: str

 class Request2(BaseModel)
   a: str
   b: List[<List of other Model, for example>]
```

is there a way to put in Body class both requests so it will fill the one that is needed?  probably is an easy question but I am just starting with this.

Comment: `request: Union[Request, Request2] = Field(...)`? (`Union` is available from the built-in `typing` module)

Comment: I will try your idea!